# Github Codespace - Environment Setting

Tags: github, config, github-codespaces

I started using github-codespace for branch experimentation. So far, experience has been really good. I have one problem. There are few settings about the vscode environment I would prefer, e.g. color theme.
Is there way to set config for the environment (for instance upload vscode config file) as a default setting for codespaces in my account?

Note: I saw some options for prebuild, but I am asking for a shorter way to do it (e.g. choose default option in github or upload config file for vscode settings)

Also, I would appreciate if you could tell me how I can make a feature request if this does not exists. I could not find a relevant repo in github for this issues

I tried searching for repo to write an issue, but could not find relevant repo.

Comment: Have you enabled  settings sync for your CodeSpaces? You can turn it on in the account icon in the lower left corner after the CodeSpaces has started. That should sync your theme, keyboard shortcuts color settings etc...

Comment: I just enabled sync. It seems to work for all the features except for a few things, e.g. Color Theme (and other visual layout options). I could change these every time I start. But it would be nice if they are loaded with sync as well.

Comment: The theme, is that installed as extension? In that case you can install the extension into the devcontainer.json.

Comment: @jessehouwing  Yes, the theme is installed as an extension (github dark theme). Once I synced and opened another codespace, it started using synced options. Now, it is using synced options and synced themes